# How to create a strategy pattern in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, strategy-pattern

I need to develop a strategy pattern where i have a main class with other three classes where i need to refer to the objects of the other three classes using the main class object.To solve this is the strategy pattern will help me? If so please do give me the syntax in Objective-C?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of your existing question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229026

Comment: Yes but i have not mentioned anything about strategy pattern in my previous question

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You'll want to look at Objective-C's [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) mechanism. Here's a simple protocol with a single required method:

```
@protocol Strategy <NSObject>

@required
- (void) execute;

@end
```

Then you declare a class that fulfills that protocol:

```
@interface ConcreteStrategyA : NSObject <Strategy>
{
    // ivars for A
}
@end
```

The implementation must provide the `-execute` method (since it was declared as `@required`):

```
@implementation ConcreteStrategyA

- (void) execute
{
    NSLog(@"Called ConcreteStrategyA execute method");
}

@end
```

You can make a similar `ConcreteStrategyB` class, but I'm not going to show it here.

Finally, make a context class with a property maintaining the current strategy.

```
@interface Context : NSObject
{
    id<Strategy> strategy;
}
@property (assign) id<Strategy> strategy;

- (void) execute;

@end
```

Here is the implementation. The method that delegates to the strategy's `-execute` method just happens to be called -execute as well, but it doesn't have to be.

```
@implementation Context

@synthesize strategy;

- (void) execute
{
    [strategy execute];
}

@end
```

Now I'll make a few instances and put them to use:

```
ConcreteStrategyA * concreteStrategyA = [[[ConcreteStrategyA alloc] init] autorelease];
ConcreteStrategyB * concreteStrategyB = [[[ConcreteStrategyB alloc] init] autorelease];
Context * context = [[[Context alloc] init] autorelease];

[context setStrategy:concreteStrategyA];
[context execute];
[context setStrategy:concreteStrategyB];
[context execute];
```

The console output shows that the strategy was successfully changed:

```
2010-02-09 19:32:56.582 Strategy[375:a0f] Called ConcreteStrategyA execute method
2010-02-09 19:32:56.584 Strategy[375:a0f] Called ConcreteStrategyB execute method
```

Note that if the protocol does not specify `@required`, the method is optional. In this case, the context needs to check whether the strategy implements the method:

```
- (void) execute
{
    if ([strategy respondsToSelector:@selector(execute)])
        [strategy execute];
}
```

This is a common Cocoa pattern called [delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html). For more information on delegation and other design patterns in Cocoa, [see this](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html).

Comment: Thank u so much for the reply,one doubt what is the 'setStrategy' keyword here represents in the instances u have made.

Comment: The `-setStrategy:` method is automatically generated by the `@synthesize` directive. If the property is declared `retain`, it takes care of doing retain/release (but you still have to release it in `-dealloc`). But if the property is declared `assign`, it does a simple assignment as a weak reference, with the assumption that the the assigned instance is guaranteed to exist and be managed elsewhere. In that case it should not be released. …In fact, I am going to change my answer to this second form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The @protocol should i need to declare it in seperate file

Comment: Generally you declare the @protocol in the same header that uses it. The strategy pattern is extremely common in Cocoa, though it's often referred to as Delegate.

Comment: Rather than id<Strategy,NSObject>, it is usually better to make Strategy itself inherit from the <NSObject> protocol: "@protocol Strategy <NSObject>" This is almost always what you want, and simplifies usage.

Comment: @Jon: Great overview of a very useful technique.

Comment: The question of what you declare whhere is a separate question which revolves around reducing unnecessary recompilation. But I would put the protocol in its own header.

Comment: Rob, thanks for pointing out the bit on making the protocol inherit from another protocol. I'm going to change my answer to reflect that, thanks!

Comment: Now i am getting with the output, I have declared the @protocol in ConcreteStrategyA.h and ConcreteStrategyB.h files so in the Context.m there is warning as: duplicate declaration for the protocol Strategy. how should i solve this problem?

Comment: Cathy, you're getting "duplicate declaration" because, uh, you're declaring it twice. Put the protocol in a header file instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit more of a concrete example. You can put each item in a separate file. I've put it all in one file for ease of understanding.

```
//  main.m
//  StrategyWikipediaExample
//
//  Created by steve on 2014-07-08.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 steve. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

/**
 Equivalent to Java Interface
 All concrete Strategies conform to this protocol
 */
@protocol MathOperationsStrategy<NSObject>
- (void)performAlgorithmWithFirstNumber:(NSInteger)first secondNumber:(NSInteger)second;
@end

/**
 Concrete Strategies. 
 Java would say they "Extend" the interface.
 */

@interface AddStrategy : NSObject<MathOperationsStrategy>
@end
@implementation AddStrategy
- (void)performAlgorithmWithFirstNumber:(NSInteger)first secondNumber:(NSInteger)second
{
    NSInteger result = first + second;
    NSLog(@"Adding firstNumber: %ld with secondNumber: %ld yields : %ld", first, second, result);
}
@end

@interface SubtractStrategy : NSObject<MathOperationsStrategy>
@end
@implementation SubtractStrategy
- (void)performAlgorithmWithFirstNumber:(NSInteger)first secondNumber:(NSInteger)second
{
    NSInteger result = first - second;
    NSLog(@"Subtracting firstNumer: %ld with secondNumber: %ld yields: %ld", first, second, result);
}
@end

@interface MultiplyStrategy : NSObject<MathOperationsStrategy>
@end
@implementation MultiplyStrategy
- (void)performAlgorithmWithFirstNumber:(NSInteger)first secondNumber:(NSInteger)second
{
    NSInteger result = first * second;
    NSLog(@"Multiplying firstNumber: %ld with secondNumber: %ld yields: %ld", first, second, result);
}
@end

@interface Context : NSObject
@property (weak, nonatomic)id<MathOperationsStrategy>strategy; // reference to concrete strategy via protocol
- (id)initWithMathOperationStrategy:(id<MathOperationsStrategy>)strategy; // setter
- (void)executeWithFirstNumber:(NSInteger)first secondNumber:(NSInteger)second;
@end
@implementation Context
- (id)initWithMathOperationStrategy:(id<MathOperationsStrategy>)strategy
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _strategy = strategy;
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)executeWithFirstNumber:(NSInteger)first secondNumber:(NSInteger)second
{
    [self.strategy performAlgorithmWithFirstNumber:first secondNumber:second];
}
@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        id<MathOperationsStrategy>addStrategy = [AddStrategy new];
        Context *contextWithAdd = [[Context alloc] initWithMathOperationStrategy:addStrategy];
        [contextWithAdd executeWithFirstNumber:10 secondNumber:10];

    }
    return 0;
}
```